# Адаптив для сайта

Tags: html, css, адаптивная-верстка

```css
.boxes {}

.box {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  height: 0;
  width: calc(100% / 6);
  padding-top: 10%;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.box-inner {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #636363;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #77ECA6;
}
```

```html
<div class="boxes">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="box-inner"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="box-inner"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="box-inner"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="box-inner"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="box-inner"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="box-inner"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="box-inner"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="box-inner"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="box-inner"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="box-inner"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="box-inner"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="box-inner"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Есть такая адаптивная секция. Надо вместо блоков поставить картинку, чтобы она тоже была полностью адаптивной. Например вот эту:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: И в чем проблема?

Comment: При замене блока на img изображение не получается адаптивным.

Comment: Поместите изображение в блок `box-inner` и добавьте ему `width: 100%`.

Answer (score 3):

Если не важна поддержка ie 11, то можно так.

css

```
.boxes {
}
.img-fluid {
      width: 100%;
      object-fit: cover;
}
```

Разметка

```
<div class="boxes">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qhqsa.png" class="img-fluid" alt="picture">
</div>
```

Comment: Здравствуйте. Плохому учите: https://caniuse.com/#feat=object-fit В стандартной вёрстке сейчас поддерживается IE-11 и так будет ещё минимум до конца 2019 года. Поэтому если вы такой рискованный вариант предлагаете, то пожалуйста, предупреждайте об ограниченной поддержки данного свойства. Отредактируйте своё сообщение, пока минус ставлю вам.

Comment: Я никого ничему не учу. Это просто возможный вариант, один из возможных. Про ie - да, как-то я про него уже забывать стал, преждевременно.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.box {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  height: 0;
  width: calc(100% / 6);
  padding-top: 10%;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.box-inner {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #636363;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #77ECA6;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="boxes">
  <div class="box">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qhqsa.png" alt="#" class="box-inner">
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qhqsa.png" alt="#" class="box-inner">
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qhqsa.png" alt="#" class="box-inner">
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qhqsa.png" alt="#" class="box-inner">
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qhqsa.png" alt="#" class="box-inner">
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qhqsa.png" alt="#" class="box-inner">
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qhqsa.png" alt="#" class="box-inner">
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qhqsa.png" alt="#" class="box-inner">
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qhqsa.png" alt="#" class="box-inner">
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qhqsa.png" alt="#" class="box-inner">
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qhqsa.png" alt="#" class="box-inner">
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qhqsa.png" alt="#" class="box-inner">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: При уменьшении размера экрана появляются отступы, как можно исправить?

Answer (score 1):

```css
.boxes {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.box {
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #636363;
  width: 16.666667%;
  padding-top: 13.541667%; /* (1/6) * (390/480) */
  background: url(//i.stack.imgur.com/Qhqsa.png) center/cover no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="boxes">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Вообще, это можно по-разному реализовать.

У вас же здесь что-то через `position: absolute;` это плохая практика, я бы использовал как крайнюю меру.

Первое, что приходи на ум, это использовать flexbox, пожалуйста:

```css
.boxes {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.box {
  flex: 0 0 16.666667%;
  max-width: 16.666667%;
}

.image {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="boxes">
  <div class="box">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qhqsa.png" alt="" class="image">
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qhqsa.png" alt="" class="image">
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qhqsa.png" alt="" class="image">
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qhqsa.png" alt="" class="image">
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qhqsa.png" alt="" class="image">
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qhqsa.png" alt="" class="image">
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qhqsa.png" alt="" class="image">
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qhqsa.png" alt="" class="image">
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qhqsa.png" alt="" class="image">
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qhqsa.png" alt="" class="image">
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qhqsa.png" alt="" class="image">
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qhqsa.png" alt="" class="image">
  </div>
</div>
```

Нужно обязательно проверять кроссбраузерность. Я проверил данный пример для вас в IE-11 и последних: edge, safari, chrome, firefox. Остаются мобильные.